# Git: about to fork my own project

Tags: git, branch

I am a very basic git user; I basically only use the commands `git add -a` (to add files after modifying them) and then `git commit -m "what I did"` and then `git push` (to push it to my server).

Now I want to do something *very* drastic to my codebase. Something that might possibly not work -- and I will have to revert back to where I was.

How do I do that? Do I create a "branch"? Or a tag? Or something else?

I am after a set of simple commands with simple explanations. also to then return to the original HEAD, or to then (maybe) merge the changes into HEAD (which won't have changed)

Merc.

Comment: Yes, a branch sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Not git, but it is a really good primer for DCVS in general: [hg init](http://hginit.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a branch.

```
git checkout -b nameofyournewbranch
```

This checks out your current branch (default name is 'master') as a new branch with the name you specify. Any commits you do now will be on the new branch. If you want to leave it and go back to where you were:

```
git checkout master
```

to go back to your new branch:

```
git checkout nameofyournewbranch
```

if you want to merge your branch into your main codebase:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff nameofyourbranch
```

--no-ff means you will see it branch out of master and then branch back in, allowing you to keep track of separate features.

To see what you're doing, get a git source tree viewer of some sort e.g. [source tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), gitk etc. Much easier to understand what the branches are doing if you can see them visually.

**Update:**
To check what would happen before merging, make a temporary branch in the same place as master and merge to there:

```
git checkout -b tempbranchname master
git merge --no-ff nameofyourbranch
```

If you like it, merge it to master and it'll be as if you did it on master in the first place:

```
git checkout master
git merge tempbranchname
```

If you don't, just delete it:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D tempbranchname
```

-D means delete even if not merged to master. Use -d normally as you'll get a warning if you try to delete unmerged stuff that you would lose.

Comment: Is there a way to know what *would* happen before merging? That way, I could just check that there aren't *huge* disasters/conflicts/etc.? (Maybe update the answer...?)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1) Create new branch. And then merge it to your main branch.

```
git branch newbranch
git checkout newbranch
...
git checkout master
git merge newbranch
```

2) You can commit to your main branch and then undo your latest commits.

But I think the best way is a branching.


You can read this article to learn more about branching:

[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a couple of useful cheatsheets: [one in HTML](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html) and [one in PDF](http://zrusin.blogspot.com.es/2007/09/git-cheat-sheet.html)

The basic commands are

To show all the existing branches

```
git branch
```

To create a new branch

```
git branch BRANCHNAME
```

To change the working copy to another branch

```
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

To merge another branch into the current one

```
git merge BRANCHNAME
```